# Rails query with array quoted using the asterisk parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function which takes `*` parameter as for passing an array.

```
def has_role?(*role_names)
  self.roles.where(:name => role_names).present?
end
```

where I can call it like:

```
user.has_role?(['super admin', 'member'])
```

or like

```
user.has_role?('super admin', 'member')
```

or like

```
user.has_role?('member')
```

When I have two parameters to pass, how can I do it with a list and a parameter?

For example, I have a another function the scopes down a similar query:

```
 def has_account_role?(role_names, account)
    self.account_user_roles.joins(:role).where('roles.name = ? AND account_id = ?', role_names, account.id).present?
 end
```

If I add a `*` to `has_account_role` like this `has_account_role?(*role_names, account)` and call `user.has_account_role?(['member', 'supervisor'], account)` I get the error: `can't quote Array`

I tried changing the query from `= ?` to `IN (?)` but get the same issue. If I try to change the query to something like `...where(:name => role_names)...` I lose the scoping that `role.name` provides the filtering on the association.

How do I pass an array into this query without making it overly complete or inefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to reverse the argument order and let the splat (`*`) swallow up everything that isn't the `account`:

```
def has_account_role?(account, *role_names)
```

Then you'd say things like this:

```
user.has_account_role?(account, ['member', 'supervisor'])
user.has_account_role?(account, 'member', 'supervisor')
```

You'd also want to use the hash form of `where` inside the method:

```
self.account_user_roles
    .joins(:role)
    .where(roles: { name: role_names }, account_id: account.id)
    .present?
```

so that `where` can use the appropriate SQL (`roles.name = ...` or `roles.name in (...)`) depending on what `role_names` ends up looking like.

BTW, a splat in a method signature:

```
def has_role?(*role_names)
  #... 
end
```

simply collects all the splatable arguments to the method into a single array (called `role_names` in this case) but it doesn't flatten the array. That means that these two calls:

```
user.has_role?(['super admin', 'member'])
user.has_role?('super admin', 'member')
```

are different things. In the first one, `role_names` looks like `[['super admin', 'member']]` (i.e. an array inside an array) and in the second one, `role_names` is just `['super admin', 'member']` (i.e. just a simple array). The `where(:name => role_names)` inside the method will flatten the array behind your back but they're still quite different as far as `has_role?` and the caller are concerned and not every method that `has_role?` calls will flatten arrays the way `where` does.

With that in mind, you might want to manually flatten your splats:

```
def has_role?(*role_names)
  role_names = role_names.flatten
  # Do whatever needs to be done now that you know that
  # `role_names` is a flat array.
  # ...
end
```